# Automatic Google Product Taxonomy (category) based on EAN

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-shopping-api

I have a database of many products withing also many categories.
I get the data from several suppliers whom each use their own way to describe category taxonomies. So i am looking to have a more standard approach.

Google uses product category taxonomies for Google shopping: https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt

When adding a shopping feed, google will try to match the product if the category taxonomy is not added manually. More info here: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324436

So i was wondering since Google tries to match automatically, is there an API that supports this feature?
Or is there other way to automatically match the products? I do have the EAN/UPC for each product, or alternatively the name and description.

Ideally i would send the EAN/UPS to an API which returns the category ID, but i don't seem to be able to find that solution.

As the database is rather large it would be near impossible to do a manual mapping, so that is not a solution at the moment.

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to this?